# Should a java class x that extends class y, which implements interface z, also implement interface z

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism

I have an interface z. It is implemented by class y. I have another class x that inherits class y. Since y implements the contract specified by class z, x does the same, as it extends class y. Should it therefore also implement interface z?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. If the interface is implemented somewhere in the hierarchy of your current class, then that is enough.

In the end, an interface just defines a few methods that a class should contain. To your subclass this is no different than if it were "normal" methods from the top class.

Sample:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new X().test();
        new Y().test();
    }
}

class X extends Y{

}

class Y implements Z{
    @Override
    public void test() {
        System.out.println("in Y");
    }
}

interface Z {
    public void test();
}
```

This will simply output

> in Y
>   in Y

If we change the definition of `X` to

```
class X extends Y implements Z
```

Then the code will still compile without a problem, output stays the same.

If we however implement this method in `X` then we will hide the method implementation from `Y`.

Comment: Is this an accepted software practice, or is it that it makes no difference?

Comment: I don't know if it is an accepted practice but it wouldn't make sense if it is. You can just use the same code (including `@Override` annotation) to override the method from the baseclass.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a lot of such examples in java.util.*, for instance List -> ArrayList -> RoleList

Answer (score 0):

I believe that x.isAssignableFrom(z) will be false unless x explicitly implements z in it's declaration.  (even though the superClass implements z).

Comment: I'm not familiar with this method, and its purpose

Comment: It is used in reflection to determine if an object will fulfill the interface specified.  Example Account implements Debitable interface (which contains the debit() method).  CheckingAccount extends Account. A user may test a checkingAccount object to see if it is Debitable by asking checkingAccount.getClass().isAssignableFrom(Debitable.class)  before calling the debit() method on it.

Comment: This is incorrect. `isAssignableFrom()` accomplishes the same thing as `instanceof`, and a reference variable for Z can certainly hold an object of type X in the OP's example regardless of whether or not X explicitly implements Z.

Comment: actually isAssignableFrom() returns false for both the class and the super class when the interface is passed as the argument, my mistake.

Comment: However there is still a difference from the reflection viewpoint. This code snippet illustrates that. 
        CheckingAccount checkingAccount = new CheckingAccount();

        Account account = new Account();

        System.out.println("Checking Account assignable from Debitable:" + Arrays.asList(checkingAccount.getClass().getInterfaces()).contains(Debitable.class));
        System.out.println("Account assignable from Debitable:" + Arrays.asList(account.getClass().getInterfaces()).contains(Debitable.class));